# Differentiating with algebraic manipulation rather than product rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Of: $(xy)^{0.5} + x + y^2 = 0$.

The solution provided on the bottom of page 13 of this pdf: https://www.biochemtuition.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/CH4-1.pdf

shows the method of applying product rule initially.

I instead want to square both sides and solve accordingly. This is my working out - but I cannot get the same answer. Can someone please help.

This is my working out:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ixqP.jpg

Comment: It would be helpful if you wrote out your working using MathJax (see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)). I guess not doing this is why your question got a -1 downvote and a close vote.

Answer (score 0):

If you substitute $\sqrt{xy}=-x-y^2$ to the book's solution, you will get yours.